# why don't we need to compile asp.net code when we add html server controllers

Tags: asp.net

I am new to asp.net framework. I noted that when we add coding in code-behind file we need to compile the web application since it can be understand only .net framework. However, I noted that HTML server controller can be added to aspx file, just save it and render the changes in browser.

My question is server controllers are first run on server, then server send the html to browser. why don't they(html server controle) code not need to compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reson to not need to compile html server controllers again and again when we add them to aspx files. 
Answer is html server controller are already compiled in to dll. thefore, no need to compile them. we can just use them.

Answer (score 2):

You can check out the [Understanding ASP.NET Dynamic Compilation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms366723)

Comment: Thanks for the link, But this is not clear explain why we not need to compile second time if the cache is different.If we add a html server controller to aspx file, we don't need to compile the project.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of web application it is required to build your solution/project in order to run it in browser.

The reason behind this all the changes in C#/VB codes will be wrapped in a `dll` in bin folder. All code been compiled in dll file either in debug or release mode. When you run your application on browser it will execute the operation according the dll build that's why if you change anything in code files than it doesn't effect until you build it again.

HTML source files don't relies on any `dll` that's why they don't require build in order to reflect their changes.

However if you create any website rather than a web application it also doesn't require any build.

Comment: In asp.net there are inbuilt html server controllers (they say html server controllers optimized for run on server), I thought as it name implies html server controles first compile in server and after processing the code it send the html to browser. Since it is not plain html controllers, I am not still clear about this? Could you explain this?

Comment: have a look on http://forums.asp.net/post/3416238.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478973.aspx